# Workflow to maintain two editions of the same source tree in Git

Tags: git

Our `master` is the main branch and snapshots of it are sent to our client at each release. Simultaneously we sometimes deploy it to our staging environment, which is quite different from the client's production environment, thus requiring a lot of scattered code changes (too much to fit in the config file and irrelevant to the client). I tried maintaining a `staging` branch and rebasing it with the changes made to `master` but I always ended up with several issues, e.g. developing on `staging` and sending the changes to `master` without the usual staging specific modifications; a merge instead of a rebase was no better. Currently I maintain a patch file that I apply to `master` each time I want to try it out on our staging environment :/ Then I undo it before continuing development.

I wonder if there's a better workflow to allow development like this.

Comment: "I wonder if there's a better workflow to allow development like this." Sure. Match production as closely as possible in staging. Have all the remaining (ideally minimal) differences (database passwords, for example) be in a environment file that's not checked into Git. What's even the point of having staging if it's massively different from production?

Comment: We don't have access to the client's production environment. The patch file applied each time already has 300 lines, unsuitable to fit the standard config file; examples of changes applied are workarounds to the query building logic to allow using oracle dblinks, which have many restrictions...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your workflow correctly, the one of the main sources of problems is doing development on the `staging` branch.

If the only goal of `staging` to is maintain the changes that are necessary for running on the staging cluster, then you can try the following workflow.

1. Do all development on `master`,
2. Keep the tip of `staging` as the one commit that maintains the changes for the staging cluster.
3. Whenever you need to run staging tests, rebase staging against master.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, to test something on the staging environment I'd need to first commit the changes to `master`, then rebase `staging`, right? If the changes are wrong, then I'll have to undo on both branches, no? I don't have the freedom of free editing and playing as I usually have before **add** and **commit**...

Comment: @AndréRodrigues, If you just wanted to try something without even committing, then I'd making the changes in the working tree directly on the `staging` branch, and then test those changes. If those changes do not work discard them. If they do work, then do `git stash; git checkout master; git stash pop`, followed by add and commit. You can then update your `staging` branch by rebasing against master as I describe in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Git (> 2.5 and even before under the contrib folder) contains the option to work on **multiple** branches at once using the `workdir`

Workdir is a way to use a single repo while having many branches checked out at the same time.

```
git-new-workdir project-dir new-workdir branch
```

---

This command allow you to work simultaneously on several branches side by side.
What the function does is simply creating a shallow copy of your `git` folder (type tree .git in the new folder to see where it actually points to) and you will see that it points to the original git folder.

In the new folder you can create new commits, branches and more, and you will see it in all of your `new-workdir` folders since they share the "same" git repo.

## Demo: (Unix)

1. add the `contrib/workdir` to your path
2. set execution flags to the `git-new-workdir`
3. navigate to your current git repository

   ```
   git new-workdir . my_new_path 
   cd my_new_path
   tree .git ( you should see links to the original git repository)
   git checkout -b new_branch
   git branch (your new branch is listed)
   cd original_path
   git branch (the new branch is listed but the current branch is the original branch)
   ```

:-)

[image: Here is a screenshot of the 2 diffent branches]

Git (> 2.5) contain a feature allowing you to have multiple working directory without using this script (`git checkout --to=$path`).

Comment: I didn't knew this command... I will check it out this possibility more in depth...

Comment: Cool, in v2.7 more features were added to it, also if you like the answer feel free to vote for it.